Can't Access Wp-admin Login Page I get 500 error
When I try login into my website I get
This page isn’t working
is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
How can I resolve this?

a HTTP 500 is a generic "something went wrong look at the error logs" style message from Apache/Nginx, it's not the actual problem. Take a look at the PHP error logs on your server and you'll see the real problem, without the error message from the logs it will be impossible for people online to help you. If you're not sure where these logs are you can ask your host

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
